# Properties of undefined ( reading .toLowerCase() ), yet code still lower cases

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to match two strings, and to do that easily, I lower case them. They are both lower cased and they exist, yet it'll give me an undefined error, even though they both exist. I used console.log() to check if something was off, yet everything existed, and it was even being lowercased.

```
const progress = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./database/sv/progress.json`));

    function match(selector) {

        let matched = null;

        progress.progress.forEach(item => {

            if (Number.isInteger(Number(selector))) {
                if (item.id == selector) matched = item;
            }
            else {
                console.log(item.leader, item.leader.toLowerCase());
                if (item.leader.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase())) matched = item;
                else if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase())) matched = item;
            }
        });

        return matched;
    }
```

The code above is my match function. Its supposed to take a user input, and attempts to match it with an object value that's in an array. The main issue the error is giving me is:

`if (item.leader.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase())) matched = item;`

item.leader exists, and its able to be lower cased. in the same code I logged it and its lowercase form and everything was in order. Yet it still gave me this error. The error is at item.leader.toLowerCase()

```
...
Nemona nemona
Turo/Sada turo/sada
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
    at C:\Users\insan\OneDrive\Desktop\Oomfie\functions\sv.js:153:54
```

Wouldn't doubt if I just made a typo or something, but everything exists and .toLowerCase() works as intended as seen above the error, yet it'll give me the error anyways. Help would be appreciated.

```js
const test = {
    "data": [
        {
            "leader": "Leader",
            "name": "Name"
        },
        {
            "leader": "Other test",
            "name": "Other test"
        }
    ]
}

selector = "Leader"; //User Inputted

function match(selector) {

    let matched;

    test.data.forEach(item => {

        if (item.leader.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase())) matched = item;
        else if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase())) matched = item;

    });

    console.log(matched);

    return matched; //Returns whatever is matched
}

match(selector)
```

The above snippet works, so im not sure if I should just re-write the code now. I once saw a video about zero width space and considering that might be it, yet im not sure.

Comment: How have you confirmed the error is about `item.leader` and not about `selector`?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] using known good data as input which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: So `item.leader` is undefined or `item.name` is undefined or `selector` is undefined. Show how you call match and what the JSON is.

Comment: It'd be cleaner to replace that `.forEach()` setup with a `.find()` call with a (slightly) modified predicate. As it is, your code finds the *last* matching item (when it doesn't throw an exception). That might be what you want, I suppose.

Comment: @David Yes, I made sure selector wasn't the issue by taking it out of the if statement and checking it separately from item.leader, and it still pointed to it. And yes I can try to, do I edit the original problem or make a separate comment?

Comment: @NicolasPezzullo: Ideally a [mcve] in this case would be in the form of a runnable code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of issues with your code:

1. If `leader` or `name` properties are missing from `item`, your code will trigger that error. You can use `typeof` checks, or `item.leader?.toLowerCase()` (and `item.name?.toLowerCase()`)
2. Using `if (item.leader ...) else if (item.name ...)` will never check `name` if `leader` property is present. Correct structure would be `if (item.leader ... || item.name ...)`, or `if (item.leader ...)` followed by `if (item.name ...)`
3. Using `.forEach` will find the "last" match. If you have 2 `item`s with the same `leader` or `name` that matches your selector, it'll only find the last one. It also iterates through all Objects, even if it doesn't need to. Use `.find()` instead.

So, let's fix these:

```js
const test = {
  data: [{
    leader: "Missing Name",
  }, {
    name: "Missing Leader",
  }, {
    leader: "Sam",
    name: "John"
  }, {
    leader: "Sam",
    name: "Mike"
  }]
};

function match(selector) {
  return test.data.find((item) => {
    return item.leader?.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase()) || item.name?.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase());
  });
}

const matched1 = match('John');
console.log('Matched `item` 1 is:', matched1 ?? 'None');

const matched2 = match('Sam');
console.log('Matched `item` 2 is:', matched2 ?? 'None');

const matched3 = match('Mike');
console.log('Matched `item` 3 is:', matched3 ?? 'None');

const matched4 = match('Bogus');
console.log('Matched `item` 4 is:', matched4 ?? 'None');
```

Now everything works, and no errors are triggered. The code now properly checks both `item.name` and `item.leader` (and doesn't blow up if they aren't present). Additionally, it will only find the "first" match, so checking for "Sam" finds "John", as both objects have the same leader, but "John" comes first.

Edit: Missed the `id` thing in your original code too. Should be similar:

```js
const test = {
  data: [{
    leader: "Missing Name",
  }, {
    name: "Missing Leader",
  }, {
    leader: "Sam",
    name: "John"
  }, {
    leader: "Sam",
    name: "Mike"
  }, {
    id: 5,
    leader: "Bob",
    name: "Sally"
  }]
};

function match(selector) {
  return test.data.find((item) => {
    if (typeof selector === 'number') {
      return typeof item.id !== 'undefined' && item.id === selector;
    }

    return item.leader?.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase()) || item.name?.toLowerCase().includes(selector.toLowerCase());
  });
}

const matched1 = match('John');
console.log('Matched `item` 1 is:', matched1 ?? 'None');

const matched2 = match('Sam');
console.log('Matched `item` 2 is:', matched2 ?? 'None');

const matched3 = match('Mike');
console.log('Matched `item` 3 is:', matched3 ?? 'None');

const matched4 = match('Bogus');
console.log('Matched `item` 4 is:', matched4 ?? 'None');

const matched5 = match(5);
console.log('Matched `item` 5 is:', matched5 ?? 'None');

const matched6 = match(6);
console.log('Matched `item` 6 is:', matched6 ?? 'None');
```

Now using `match(5)` will return the `item` with `id: 5`, and `match(6)` returns `None` (no objects with `id` of `6`). The `typeof item.id !== 'undefined'` is optional, as `undefined === selector` will always be `false` if `id` is missing.